# 4х блоков div в одном div через less - один блок переносится на следующую строку

Tags: html, less

При создании 4х блоков div в одном div через less, один блок переносится на следующую строку. Подскажите в чем причина

```css
.col-md-4 {
  width: @widthAll / 3 - 20px;
  margin: 50px 1px;
  height: 270px;
  border-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row padding-site">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3-active">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="lamp"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/product-2.jpg" alt="twochair"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/product-3.jpg" alt="kettle"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/product-4.jpg" alt="redchair"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто замени `.col-md-4` на `.col-md-3`

```css
  .col-md-3 {
     width: @widthAll / 3 - 20px;
     margin: 50px 1px;
     height: 270px;
     border-style: none;
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row padding-site">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3-active"><a href="#"><img src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="lamp"></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="img/product-2.jpg" alt="twochair"></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="img/product-3.jpg" alt="kettle"></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="img/product-4.jpg" alt="redchair"></a></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

а почему ты в html пишешь col-md-3, а стили показываешь для col-md-4?